# How to use mysql after installing an older version of mariadb via homebrew?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, homebrew

I need to install an older version of mariadb:

```
brew install mariadb@10.1
```

I can even successfully start it:

```
brew services start mariadb@10.1
```

But when I do `mysql -uroot`

I get

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/mysql: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was able to find the issue.

First, we need to put the path in bash_profile and source it.

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mariadb@10.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
. ~/.bash_profile
```

That solves the main issue above. But the service might still fail when trying to connect with.

```
brew services stop mariadb@10.1
```

Then run by hand to see the error:

```
/usr/local/opt/mariadb@10.1/bin/mysql.server start
```

This will indicate an error:

```
vim /usr/local/var/mysql/Macbook-Pro.err
```

Looking at it gives away the reason.

In my case I had still the databases from the previous installation that happen to be the newer version than the one installing here.

I had to remove all old dbs:

```
brew uninstall mariadb@10.1
cd /usr/local/var/mysql/
sudo rm -r *
brew install mariadb@10.1
```

Now it can be started as a service

```
brew services start mariadb@10.1
```

Answer (score 0):

just link it to mariadb and stop if from updating/upgrading

```
brew install mariadb@10.3
brew link  mariadb@10.3 --force
brew pin  mariadb@10.3
```

run it

```
mysql.server start
```